# Reduction of Dimension of a projective variety by intersection with another variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety. Let $I(Y)=\langle f_1,\dots,f_k\rangle$. Let $f\in k[x_0,\dots, x_n]$ be an irreducible homogeneous polynomial such that $f\notin I(Y)$. Let $Z(f)$ be the zero set of $f$. Let $Y'=Y\cap Z(f)$. Is it true that $\dim Y'=\dim Y-1 $ ?

Comment: I think some more conditions are needed here. For example, if $Y=Z(f)$ then clearly the dimensional equality is not true.

Comment: @awllower Thanks for pointing out the mistake.  Changed it.

Comment: @awllower Added one more condition.

Comment: Won't you need some kind of transversality condition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. Let $Z=Z(f)$. Hartshorne AG I.7.2 says that the dimension of each irreducible component of $Y\cap Z$ is at least $\dim Y-1$. Suppose there were some component $A$ of $Y\cap Z$ such that $\dim A = \dim Y$. Then $A$, being a closed subset of $Y$ of the same dimension, is equal as a set to $Y$. In particular, $Y$ is a closed subvariety of $Z$. But then $f$ vanishes along $Y$, a contradiction to $f\notin I(Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true, and in fact you don't even need $f$ to be irreducible.  Generally, if $A$ is Noetherian and $f$ is a nonzerodivisor of $A$, then $A/f$ has dimension one less than that of $A$.